# equals letter start and end SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, where-clause

how to select a cells with contents (varchar) starting and ending with equals letter in SQL??

Comment: That would depend on the database. What database are you using?

Comment: Microsoft SQL server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use string functions. Assuming a table called `mytable` with a column called `col`:

```
select *
from mytable
where left(col, 1) = right(col, 1)
```

Note that this also allows values that are made of just one character - you did not tell which behavior you want in that case. You can easily avoid that, if that's what you want, with another condition on the length of the string:

```
select *
from mytable
where left(col, 1) = right(col, 1) and len(col) > 1
```